# How to check deployment history in production org

Tags: deployment, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, deployment-api, mdapideploy

In production org when I click on the deployment status, it shows a list of passed and failed deployments like below image

[image]

if it is deployed from a changeset then in name section it shows the name of the changeset but if the change is deployed from the dx then it shows an Id as showing in below image.
  in case of changeset I can click on the name of the changeset to see what is inside the change but in case of dx name is not clickable and if I click on view details button then it shows only the number of components and number tests ran but doesn't show any metadata deployed.
Could someone please help me to navigate on how to see what has been deployed from the dx in slaesforce?

Answer (score 4):

There's no way of seeing the exact elements deployed by SFDX. However, you might be able to get most of the information you need by checking the Setup Audit Trail. This shows all the changes made in the org and will include most things deployed by SFDX.

[image: Setup Audit Trail]